# How to set reply-to topic through Stomp.js

Tags: c#, javascript, jms, activemq-classic, stomp

In C# using NMS API we set Response topic for ActiveMQ in this way

```
IDestination temp = session.CreateTemporaryTopic();
ITopic consumer = session.CreateConsumer(temp);
```

And while sending message we set it like this ...

```
TextMessage reqMessage = session.CreateTextMessage(message);
reqMessage.NMSReplyTo = temp;
```

How can we do the same thing using Stomp.js?

Answer (score 1):

Most STOMP operations are done using specific headers that are placed in the Message that you send.  In this case the 'reply-to' header indicates the address where the receiving client should send its response.  So the pattern would be to send the message with the 'reply-to' header set, something like this depending on the library you are using:

```
stomp.subscribe("/temp-queue/response-queue")
stomp.publish("/queue/work-queue", "WORK", {"reply-to" => "/temp-queue/response-queue"})
```

Since you are using temp Topic you must ensure that there is subscriber prior to the response message being sent, otherwise it will not get all the replies.